# #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

```
  --Items table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items(
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    itemID varchar(10),
    itemName varchar(40),
    description varchar(100),
    unitPrice int (10),
    CONSTRAINT Items_pk PRIMARY KEY(ID,itemID)
)ENGINE=INNODB



  --Stock Table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stock(
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    availableQty int(10),
    itemID varchar(10),
    CONSTRAINT Items_fk FOREIGN KEY (itemID) REFERENCES items(itemID)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB
```

Comment: You need to create a field in order to declare it as a Foreign Key

Comment: Thank you for submitting the status report. Did you have an actual *question*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to add a foreign key constraint to something that *isn't a key*.  Note the constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT Items_fk FOREIGN KEY (itemID) REFERENCES items(itemID)
```

And note the key on `items`:

```
CONSTRAINT Items_pk PRIMARY KEY(ID,itemID)
```

`itemID` isn't the key on `items`.  You need *both* of those values in order to reference the key.  Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stock(
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    availableQty int(10),
    itemID int,
    itemItemID varchar(10),
    CONSTRAINT Items_fk FOREIGN KEY (itemID, itemItemID) REFERENCES items(ID, itemID)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB
```

Naturally, you may want to use better naming.  It's a little unintuitive at the moment because you have two things called "ID" for any given "Item".